# Hide column on screen

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

```
<input id="SubmitCommentsForBOQ" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowCommentBox('<%: detailItem.ItemId %>')" />
```

shows a comments button...I want to change this to an image, which does the same thing when clicked...

something like.. `<img src="../Images/Bubble.png" />`

How can I do this? thanks

Comment: Change the name of the JS function to `ShowCommentBoxAndImage` and do both operations in that function? Is this a trick question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
<img src="../Images/Bubble.png" onclick="ShowCommentBox('<%: detailItem.ItemId %>')"/>
```

Or I somethig not understad?